# How much memory does null value take up in dart VM?

Tags: dart, null, heap-memory

Just started learning coding, get curious how much memory takes null value in dart programming language?
I knew that in java 'null value' takes 4 bytes of memory.

Answer (score 2):

One pointer, just like every other object reference.

The object itself likely takes a little memory somewhere, but every reference to it, the thing you probably mean by "null value", is just a reference to that one object.

The size of a reference/pointer depends on whether the runtime is using 32-bit or 64-bit pointers.

Comment: ok, thank you. Cleared the topic for me.